# Python - How to give values to different functions

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop

I have been trying to send values between each function. I have created a code:

```
def filter(thread, i):

    text = "NAME".lower()

    has_good = False
    positive_keywords = i

    for ch in ['&', '#', '“', '”', '"', '*', '`', '*', '’', '-']:
        if ch in text:
            text = text.replace(ch, "")

    sentences = [text]

    def check_all(sentence, ws):
        return all(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(w), sentence) for w in ws)

    for sentence in sentences:
        if any(check_all(sentence, word.split('+')) for word in positive_keywords):
            has_good = True
            break

    if not has_good:
        sys.exit()

def testscript(thread, i):
    filter(thread, i)

def script():
    old_list = []

    old_names_list = []

    while True:
        new_names_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('names.txt')]

        for new_thread in get_random_names(): #A function that contians 100 random names

            if not new_names_list == old_names_list: 
                for i in new_names_list:
                    if not i in old_names_list:
                        threading.Thread(target=testscript, args=(new_thread, i)).start()
                old_names_list = new_names_list


            elif new_thread not in old_list: #If the names are not added in old_list. start new thread.
                threading.Thread(target=testscript, args=(new_thread,)).start()
                old_list.append(new_thread)

        else:
            randomtime = random.randint(1, 3)
            time.sleep(randomtime)
```

So what the code is following: It starts by script(). It checks if my txt file has gotten bigger and if it has it does `threading.Thread(target=testscript, args=(new_thread, i)).start()` - If it doesn't find anything in the text file it supposed to do the `elif new_thread not in old_list:`

However my problem right now is that in elif, it doesn't contain a name (which in our case is I) while in `if not new_names_list == old_names_list:` it does contain i. Meaning that I need to send `i` sometimes and sometimes not. The problem is when there is no name. It will give me an error of `missing 1 required positional argument: 'i'` and that's due to there is no name. How can I be able to send value to a thread if there is no value of that?

Comment: cant you give it a default value in the function itself. def filter(thread, i=''):

Comment: What do you mean? I dont quite sure get what you mean @vanderZonStef

Comment: For threads where you don't want to be sending an i, how do you want the `for sentence in sentences:` part to behave?  @Hellosiroverthere

Comment: Oh, I didnt thought about it. I assume what I can do is that if there is no value for sending an i, just sys.exit() @rLevv

Comment: Ok @Hellosiroverthere . Yeah there are a few different options depending on what you want to do with those threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change def testscript(thread, i): to

```
def testscript(thread, i=""):
```

Then you can call testscript and if you do not pass a second argument, the second argument will default to the empty string (you can have it default to whatever you want):

```
threading.Thread(target=testscript, args=(new_thread)).start() # when testscript receives this, it will just default i="" and pass that to filter
```

Then it will pass the empty string to filter and, in that case, I think your

```
if any(check_all(sentence, word.split('+')) for word in positive_keywords):
```

will return false if positive_keywords is given the empty string (otherwise choose a different value that causes that to always return false) and it'll move on to the sys.exit.

Alternatively, you could also use args* or kwargs** and check for a second input in testscript and just sys.exit if there isn't one or adjust filter to only assign positivekeywords and enter that sentence block when you have an i.